# JMeter - Throughput Shaping Timer - How does it work?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

This is my test plan

[image]

I have only debug sampler. 5 concurrent users for each thread group. Ramp up 1 second for all.

So overall 20 users - ramped up in 1 seconds.

Debug sampler throughput can go more than 100000/sec. As you see, no other timers except Througput shaping timer.

**Issue:**
If i run the test, I was expecting the min throughput of 15 requests/sec - upto 16 requests /sec. It is not even reaching 14 (well, except once)

How does it work?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be you might not be having enough threads in Thread groups to reach up to 15/16 RPS. Try increasing the thread count. According to the Throughput Shaping Timer plugins [wiki page](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#How-Many-Threads-I-Need-To-Produce-Desired-RPS) the formula `RPS * <max response time> / 1000` can be used to get the number of threads that needed to reach the desired RPS, but it never worked for me.

Comment: what you've written here should've been posted as a comment.

Comment: read the question carefully - Debug sampler throughput can go more than 100000/sec. As you see, no other timers except Througput shaping timer.